# What's the best layout for a python command line application?

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, distribute

What is the right way (or I'll settle for a *good* way) to lay out a command line python application of moderate complexity?  I've created a python project skeleton using paster, which gave me a few files to start with:

```
myproj/__init__.py
MyProj.egg-info/
 dependency_links.txt
 entry_points.txt
 PKG-INFO
 SOURCES.txt
 top_level.txt
 zip-safe
setup.cfg
setup.py
```

I want to know, mainly, where should my program entry point go, and how can I get it installed on the path? Does setuptools create it for me?  I'm trying to find this in the HHGTP, but maybe I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to create all that, the `.egg-info` directory is generated by setuptools.  You mention the command line, so I assumed you have a 'top level' script somewhere, let's say `myproj-bin`.  Then this would work:

```
./setup.py
./myproj
./myproj/__init__.py
./scripts
./scripts/myproj-bin
```

And then put something like this in `setup.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from setuptools import setup

setup(name="myproj",
      description='shows how to create a python package',
      version='123',
      packages=['myproj'],  # python package names here
      scripts=['scripts/myproj-bin'],  # scripts here
      )
```

There's a lot more that you can do if your project is complex, the full manual of setuptools is here: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools.